# how to write a class object in c++ into a file

Tags: c++

please tell us how to  write a object of a class into a file

after writing if a value of a data member changes, then how can be it updated in the file without causing duplicate entry

while writing to a file, when a data member is uninitialized at the moment of writing, will it cause any problem

how does file work while dealing with class object exactly

Answer (score 1):

Create an ofstream object and write to the desired path.

If you want to update simply loop and seek to that object and write.

As the file will be created in binary, you cant be able to read it in notepad, you have to read it back by ifstream object and output it into console or into text file..

Check this link http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: okay. i got it. i have an array of objects to write. i wrote them one by one using for loop. then i read from it. however these appears to be data corruption as some duplicate records are displayd

Comment: you need to write every time at end, please read that link. and kindly delete that file and start writing to that file, because your entire object will be written at once. one object size will be fixed, and while reading it back, same way you have to read with same object/class.

Comment: You can download "sumita arora c++ class 12" This is a book, very famous in India for std 12. This contains superb chapters and codes for filehandling.

Comment: these input and output looks quite OK. note: i havent checked in by running. So whats the problem now? only updating?

Comment: hi plz see this thread. i created a new one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13787210/c-file-handling-unable-to-access-records-in-order